# how to find & label centroids of clusters created by hclust() in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, centroid, hclust

I read the thread [there](https://www.biostars.org/p/13143/) but in this thread, the answer is saying using the column means for the cluster i (so if I have 3 clusters in total, i = 1,2,3; and if I have 2 clusters overall, i = 1,2). 
I will copy and paste their answers here:

```
clusters = cutree(hclust(dist(USArrests)), k=5) # get 5 clusters

# function to find medoid in cluster i
clust.centroid = function(i, dat, clusters) {
    ind = (clusters == i)
    colMeans(dat[ind,])
}

sapply(unique(clusters), clust.centroid, USArrests, clusters)

              [,1]       [,2]   [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
Murder    11.47143   8.214286   5.59  14.2  2.95
Assault  263.50000 173.285714 112.40 336.0 62.70
UrbanPop  69.14286  70.642857  65.60  62.5 53.90
Rape      29.00000  22.842857  17.27  24.0 11.51
```

But that does not make sense to me! If I have a data set with 3 variables/columns, and I only want 2 clusters, using their method, only the column means for column 1 & 2 are used, and column mean for 3rd column will never be calculated!

Let's say I created such data table:

```
a = c(1,2,3,4,2,2,5,3,1)
b = c(4,5,2,2,1,1,1,1,3)
c = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1)
abc = data.frame(a=a, b=b, c=c)
str(abc)
```

And the last line will return the following data table:

```
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: num  1 2 3 4 2 2 5 3 1
 $ b: num  4 5 2 2 1 1 1 1 3
 $ c: num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

I then scale the data:

```
abc_scaled = scale(abc)
```

Calculate distance and create hierarchical cluster and cut the tree:

```
distance = dist(abc_scaled, method="euclidean")
hcluster = hclust(distance, method="ward.D")
clusters = cutree(hcluster, h = (max(hcluster$height) - 0.1))
```

Let's say i get 2 clusters as result, how can i compare the centroids of the 2 clusters? and how can i add the labels to the clusters???

Comment: but here you're using the three columns of your data.frame ? This part is not clear to me "Let's say I have a data set with 3 variables/columns with 4th column being the response var (which i wont use in clustering process), and I only want 2 clusters, using their method, I'll only use the column means for column 1 & 2 (beacause there's only 2 clusters), and column mean for 3rd column will never be used!"

Comment: hi @VincentBonhomme. so the data set has 4 columns in total, with 4th column being the response var and so won't be included in the clustering process. and so i only have 3 columns of data in my example. does this make more sense now?

Comment: But this is still unclear to me= "only the column means for column 1 & 2 are used, and column mean for 3rd column will never be calculated!"

Comment: hi @VincentBonhomme, if you read the thread i have linked to you'd understand what im talking about. maybe i should copy over their answers to my post so its easier for you to understand? i can do that right now.

Comment: I actually read it but still don't understand. Maybe I'm the problem ;-)

Comment: hi @VincentBonhomme so i just added their answers and a bit more explanations to my post. does this clear up your confusion now?

Comment: Got it now, thanks. I think [this page](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/Cluster2a.html) is a better starting point that the thread.